# Клиент серверное приложение на lua

Tags: клиент-сервер, lua

Задача такая:
У меня есть клиенты, использующие мои программные продукты. Нужно защитить от распространения на складчинах. Хочу сделать сервер. К нему будут подключаться клиенты с авторизацией. Далее клиент запрашивает что то важное для работы приложения (идеально если часть кода) - сервер ему выдает. Как это можно осуществить? Подскажите пожалуйста что почитать? В каком направлении двигаться? По сути я начинающий. То что умею делать - делаю хорошо. Но нужно расти. Мои программы работают на луа. Соответственно было бы идеально решить такую задачу на луа. 
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Попутно изучаю питон... Если это как то поможет

Answer (score 0):

Одназначно [openresty](https://openresty.org/en/). Это `nginx` с возможностью добавлять функционал на `lua`

Comment: Спасибо. Буду изучать.